# Profiling submodule dependencies within a Perl module

Tags: perl, profiling

I've got a big collection of utility subroutines stuck in a single giant `myUtil.pm` Perl module. I'm trying to get a profile of how the pile of subroutines depend on each other.

I found [Module::ScanDeps](http://search.cpan.org/~rschupp/Module-ScanDeps-1.17/lib/Module/ScanDeps.pm), which looks for dependencies *across* modules. Is there a similar tool which looks at dependencies *within* a module?

I'd prefer to have a static analysis, as I'm not very confident that I've got enough test cases to cover all of the code paths.

Answer (score 3):

There's probably something newer (and PPI-based), but the older B::Xref does this.

Foo.pm:

```
package Foo;
use 5.014;
use warnings;
sub foo { bar() }
sub bar { $_[0]-- and bar() }
sub baz { foo(); bar () }
1;
```

`perl -MO=Xref -e'use Foo'`:

```
...
File Foo.pm
  Subroutine (definitions)
    Package Foo
      &bar              s4
      &baz              s6
      &foo              s4
  Subroutine Foo::bar
    Package Foo
      &bar              &5
  Subroutine Foo::baz
    Package Foo
      &bar              &6
      &foo              &6
  Subroutine Foo::foo
    Package Foo
      &bar              &4
```

Comment: Hmm.. `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` - I didn't think my module was _that_ messy :/

Comment: interesting; report it as a bug

Comment: coding something up yourself using PPI shouldn't be that much work

Comment: Oh cool! This is the first I've come across PPI! I'll leave the question open for now, in case someone knows of something out there.